# Embedding v8 with Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, v8

I'm trying to embed the v8 engine to my C++ application. I use Visual C++ 2010. I've built it successfully using this command:

```
scons env="INCLUDE:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include,LIB:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib"
```

And then, I:

- added the **v8/include** directory to Configuration Properties ->  C/C++ -> General --> Additional Include Directories
- added the **v8/v8.lib** file to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

When I try to compile the basic "Hello World" example from the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/get_started.html#hello) page, it shows me the following linking error:

```
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__accept@12
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__listen@8
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__send@16
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__freeaddrinfo@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__timeGetTime@0
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__recv@16
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__setsockopt@20
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__shutdown@8
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ntohs@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__getaddrinfo@16
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__htonl@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ntohl@4
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8
1>v8.lib(platform-win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__connect@12
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to link to WinSock (`Ws2_32.lib`).

Comment: Yes, and `WINMM.LIB` either. Thanks!